# Is there a known example of a finitely presented group with subexponential growth that isn't polynomial?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory, subgroup-growth

The Grigorchuk group is finitely generated and has subexponential non-polynomial growth but I'm not aware of a finite presentation. Does a finite presentation imply that the group is polynomial or exponential as well?

Comment: Grigorchuk himself credits I. Lysenok with a presentation of his group, but one of the relations is parametrized by an integer k so the presentation is not finite. He also mentions that the Grigorchuk group is not finitely presentable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no known examples of such groups. Grigorchuk group is infinitely presented and so are all other known infinite finitely generated groups of intermediate growth (there are many examples: Gupta-Sidki, Erschler, and others).